# NET MAUI where and how to store temporary data

Tags: c#, maui

Let's say that I need to use a list of data (in picker for example) in more then 2 views.
Is there a way to store the data of this list temporary somewhere in the memory and populate it on app start.
Is Preferences built for this, or it is just for storing app data, like JWT, ... (I saw for that is a special storage called SecureStorage).

thnx

Comment: Do you need the data to be persistent between app starts or do you just need access to it from anywhere in the app? The `Preferences` are designed for persistent storage (only while the app is installed), which sometimes has a performance impact. `SecureStorage` is encrypted on Android and on iOS it's using the Keychain, which persists even after uninstalling the app on iOS (on Android all app data gets deleted upon uninstalling). If you need access to non-persistent data, then you could use some kind of data service with properties that you provide via dependency injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define static method and propery and fill them while the project is standing up. If you want the data to be deleted and refilled in a certain time interval, you can use MemoryCache, there is more detailed information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-7.0
or you can store this data on Session https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: You are right, I totaly forgot IMemoryCache

Comment: Hi @Wasyster,  please mark this reply as answered if you accept this answer.  Thanks.

Comment: *"you can store this data on Session"* A **session** is a **server-side** concept. **Maui** is a **client-side** UI framework. I think that second link is not applicable to Maui. The first two recommendations (statics; MemoryCache) should work fine with Maui.